# Is there any way possible to tail a falling star or comet-like particle?

Tags: particles, edit-mode

I am trying to set up a simple space like gravity particle system for animation, but I have no idea how to make a tail on a particle to make it look like the way I want (Including the gradient) I basically have the particle system ready, but I just don't know how to make the tail. Any help would be appreciated, Thanks!

[image: This is the example]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

**For the particles:**

1. Start with a sphere
2. move one vertex far away using `proportional editing`  so that neighbor vertices are also stretched proportionally
   [image]
3. to create the cloud of particles, use 2 `array modifiers` to create a matrix, apply the modifiers and `separate by loose parts`
   [image]
   [image]
4. use `proportional editing` with `Random` and `smooth` fall off in order to arrange the particles. Alternatively, use `Randomize Tranform`.
   [image]
5. create a gradient based shader, use Color Ramps to control color, emission and transparency fall offs (don't forget to turn `Alpha Blend` mode for transparency to work)

[image]

**For the background:**

Create a world shader based on spherical or linear gradient. Use the Vector Mapping scale, position and rotations to control gradient position in the sky.

[image]

**For animation:** Here is the same object used in a particle system (added plane emitter and moved camera around):

[image]

Comment: I see this is made for a still image, but will I be able to make this as a particle system? I know how to, but I've had issues with mapping material node and particle systems when the particle moves. I am trying to make an animation with it

Comment: Nothing prevent you form using this comet object in a particle system...

Comment: I added a screenshot of the same scene but using a particle system instead of Array modifier

Comment: Ok, I'll give this a try, I was on the road for the past day getting home safe, Thanks

Comment: Glad it helped!